# Adding Multiple Payments using QBXML

Tags: xml, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, qbxml, qbwc

I am trying to add new payments in a batch to quickbooks using XML requests to [Quickbooks Web Connector](http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/QuickBooks_Web_Connector),  my request for a single payment looks like this

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                <?qbxml version="2.1"?>
                <QBXML>
                        <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
                                <ReceivePaymentAddRq>
                                        <ReceivePaymentAdd>
                                                <CustomerRef>
                                                        <ListID>' . $arr['customerRef'] . '</ListID>
                                                </CustomerRef>
                                                <TxnDate>' . $arr['dateTime'] . '</TxnDate>
                                                <RefNumber>' . $arr['paymentRefNum'] . '</RefNumber>
                                                <TotalAmount>' . $arr['totalAmt'] . '</TotalAmount>
                                                <PaymentMethodRef>
                                                        <FullName>' . $arr['paymentMethodRef'] . '</FullName>
                                                </PaymentMethodRef>
                                                <Memo>' . $arr['paymentMethodRef'] . '</Memo>
                                                <AppliedToTxnAdd>
                                                        <TxnID>' . $arr['paymentRefNum'] . '</TxnID>
                                                        <PaymentAmount>' . $arr['totalAmt'] . '</PaymentAmount>
                                                </AppliedToTxnAdd>
                                                <IsAutoApply>true</IsAutoApply>

                                        </ReceivePaymentAdd>
                                </ReceivePaymentAddRq>
                        </QBXMLMsgsRq>
                </QBXML>';
                return $xml;
```

I was using [this](https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbsdk-current/samples/xmlfiles/legacy/ReceivePaymentAddRq.xml) as a template and I can get a payment in to Quickbooks but I need to find out how to handle multiple payments in one XML request as it should be going in as a batch.  If anyone has any insight they can provide that would really help.  I have searched the Intuit developer documents and some other ones like ConsoliByte's wiki and I only see single requests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Repeat the ReceivePaymentAdd section.

Comment: I did do this already and it did not look to work, should there be anything that I should be adding to the second request?

Comment: Specifically what about it didn't work? Post your request, or post the error message you got back.